# Why is the SeekBar in my dialog not drawn correctly when the orientation is horizontal?

Tags: android, android-layout, seekbar, android-dialogfragment

> ## Closed: Not Reproducible.
>
> After making seemingly unrelated changes to the app, the problem has resolved itself.

The application I'm working on requires asking the user to set the StrokeWidth for a Paint object. To accomplish this, I've created a custom dialog.

In the vertical orientation, the dialog looks fine.

[image: Custom Dialog in Vertical Orientation]

However, in the horizontal orientation, the SeekBar is a bit messed up.

[image: Custom Dialog in Horizontal Orientation]

The SeekBar functions properly, just the line and progress bar are not drawn properly.

Here's the code I use to create the View that's used.

```
private View createView() {
    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );
    linearLayoutParams.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutParams);

    this.lineDrawView = new LineDrawView(getActivity());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lineDrawLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    lineDrawLayoutParams.setMargins(25,25,25,0);
    lineDrawView.setMaximumStrokeWidth(this.maximum_stroke_width);
    lineDrawView.setStrokeWidth(this.stroke_width);
    linearLayout.addView(lineDrawView, lineDrawLayoutParams);

    this.seekBar = new SeekBar(getActivity());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams seekbarLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );
    seekbarLayoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    seekBar.setMax((int)this.maximum_stroke_width);
    seekBar.setPadding(64,64,64,84);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    seekBar.setProgress((int)this.stroke_width);
    linearLayout.addView(seekBar, seekbarLayoutParams);

    return linearLayout;
}
```

And the code that creates the dialog

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle bundle) {
    View view = createView();
    this.alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setTitle(this.titleId)
            .setView(view)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    onStrokeWidthChanged();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            }).create();
    return this.alertDialog;
}
```

How can I get the SeekBar to display properly in either orientation?